# Efficient way of iterating over large npz files

Tags: python, arrays, json, file, numpy

I have 50000+ npz files (file size 15MB) each with three numpy arrays A, B, C.

A is a numpy array of shape (33000,); B is a numpy array of shape (33000,) and C is a bit array of shape (33000,224,224) of `uint8` type.

```
npz_file_dict = np.load(npz_file_path)
num_records = len(npz_file_dict['A'])

A = npz_file_dict['A']
B = npz_file_dict['B']
C = npz_file_dict['C']


def get_items(num_records):
   for i in range(num_records)
      yield A[i], B[i], C[i]
for a,b,c in get_items(num_records):
   # do some work with (a,b,c)
   # store the result in a json format with {'a' : a, 'b' : b, 'c' : c}
```

The for loop takes a really long time to finish (sometimes more than 35 minutes for 30000 records). Is there an efficient way to parse through the records?

Edit : I tried doing memory mapped numpy arrays but it does not seem to improve performance as they have effect only on npy files.

Edit : Need critique on my proposed approach.

I've resorted to using memory maps to speed up my iteration, for every file I read I spend some amount of time (in what I call the setup phase) to map this huge numpy array to a file pointer.

```
num_records = len(npz_file_dict['np_cids'])
print(num_records)


start_memmap = time()
data = npz_file_dict['C']

print('Time to read data {}'.format(time() - start_memmap))


filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'newfile.dat')

print('Path to file',  filename)
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(num_records, 224,224))
fp[:] = data[:]

finish_memmap = time()

print('Time to create memmap {}'.format(finish_memmap - start_memmap))
```

Once this setup is done, I simply iterate over the A and B arrays in the for loop and use the `fp` to grab the corresponding `i^th` record. The advantage of this approach is the iterations are quite fast. The disadvantage is the setup time ranging anywhere between 50 secs on single process mode and 100 seconds on multiprocessing mode.

If you amortize the setup time over the set of 30000 records, it is around 3.3 ms. During the iteration, the read is quite fast -- a few hundred micro-seconds. That puts the overall time taken per record somewhere around 5 ms. This is a 96% speed compared my earlier approach which took 150ms per record.

Comment: `npz_file_dict['A']` is an array.  Same for the other names.  To clarify this start with `A = npz_file_dict['A']`, etc.  Regardless of the source, iterating on the elements of an array is slow.  If you want speed you need to work with the 'whole' array, not just one 'record' at a time.  But you don't tell us what that 'some work' is, so we can't help much.  Creating that `json` entry, record by record, will also be slow.

Comment: Would you consider using the multiprocessing module https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html? Or are you looking for a matrix math solution to speed this up?

Comment: How long does it take if you run without doing any processing, e.g. `def somework(a, b, c):pass`?  That will give you a good idea if the bottleneck is here, or in the processing you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can clean up the code with:

```
npz_file_dict = np.load(npz_file_path)
A = npz_file_dict['A']   # (33000,) shape array
B = npz_file_dict['B']
C = npz_file_dict['C']

for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C):
   # do some work with (a,b,c)
   # store the result in a json format with {'a' : a, 'b' : b, 'c' : c}
```

This makes it clear that you are working with arrays that you have loaded from the  file.  I don't know if it will speed things up or not; that depends on whether the `npz` loader uses some sort of cache with repeated `npz_file_dict['A]` accesses or not.

But regardless of how they are created or loaded, iteration through numpy arrays is slow - much slower than if you used compiled 'whole-array' operations on them.  Iteration on lists is faster.  In fact it might help to do

```
for a,b,c in zip(A.tolist(), B.tolist(), list(C):
    ...
```

`A.tolist()` is a fast way of turning an array into a list.  I don't use it on `C` because it is 3d, and I assume you want to use `C[i,:,:]` as an array, rather than a nest list.  Though since you are writing `c` to a `json` you may want it to be a list of lists anyways.

===

Iterating over a `memmap` array is quite a bit slower than iterating over an in-memory array:

```
In [1]: C=np.ones((3000,224,224))                                               
In [2]: np.savez('bigC.npz',C=C)                                                
In [3]: fp = np.memmap('bigC.dat', dtype=C.dtype, mode='w+', shape=C.shape)     
In [4]: fp[:] = C[:]                                                            
In [5]: %%timeit  
   ...: for i in range(3000): 
   ...:     c = C[i] 
   ...:                                                                         
566 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %%timeit  
   ...: for i in range(3000): 
   ...:     c = fp[i] 
   ...:      
   ...:                                                                         
9.74 ms ± 94.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Iterating over the `npz` load is indeed slow - my test is still running:

```
In [8]: %%timeit d = np.load('bigC.npz') 
   ...: for i in range(3000): 
   ...:     c = d['C'][i]
```

Test with one initial load:

```
In [243]: d = np.load('bigC.npz')                                               
In [244]: %%timeit  
     ...: D = d['C'] 
     ...: for i in range(3000): 
     ...:     c = D[i] 
     ...:                                                                       
2.17 s ± 27.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [245]: %%timeit  
     ...: D = d['C'] 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                       
2.14 s ± 6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So a one time load of the large array from the `npz` is an avoidable, but you certainly don't want to repeatedly load it for each row.  Dumping it to a memmap might help if the array is so large it doesn't fit in memory, it isn't an improvement over an in-memory array.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried a memmap based approach and was wondering if you might be interested in it -- its edited in the question.

Comment: I don't see what copying `data` to a memmap is doing for you. Why not just access the ith record of `data` directly? `data[i,:,:]`